# Can I load human as soft body in pybullet?

Tags: python, pybullet

I do have solid model of human (.stl and .obj files). How can load it as soft body in PyBullet ? Any suggestions.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What is your own effort here so far (what have you tried)? Please ask specific coding questions here, as the format is not suitable for discussions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have tried this but you can use fuction loadSoftBody:

```
p.loadSoftBody("name_of_your_object.obj")
```

Check this example from pybullet repo: https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3/blob/master/examples/pybullet/examples/load_soft_body.py